# Wifi settings doesn't show any networks On Ubuntu Server 22.04.2

Tags: networking, server, wireless

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 and my wifi card seems to be recognized but I can't see any available networks in the list that appears when triggering the settings UI in Gnome

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Z1hS.jpg)

I looked up various solutions for this issue and doesn't seem like my situation fits any, could someone help me debug the issue?

Troubleshooting steps:

```
> nmcli device
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION 
wlp4s0  wifi      disconnected  --         
enp5s0  ethernet  unmanaged     --         
lo      loopback  unmanaged     --
```

then I tried

```
> rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci1: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

the troubleshooter suggested I look into the hardware so I did that too

```
> sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 00
       serial: a8:93:4a:e1:87:df
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7921e driverversion=5.15.0-75-generic firmware=____010000-20220209150915 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:87 memory:e0300000-e03fffff memory:e0400000-e0403fff memory:e0404000-e0404fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: enp5s0
       version: 03
       serial: a8:a1:59:5d:77:03
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.15.0-75-generic duplex=full firmware=0. 4-1 ip=192.168.50.114 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:34 memory:fca00000-fca1ffff ioport:f000(size=32) memory:fca20000-fca23fff
```